# Ansible "local_action" with uri module to post a json body with variables

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to HTTP POST a JSON body with some Ansible variables filled in. The task must be run as a `local_action`, so I'm forced to use the shorthand syntax for the `uri module`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with a remote server using a local action,
this answer uses JSON inside a Jinja template, inside Ansible shorthand syntax for the module, inside a YAML string for the `local_action`'s `module:`

The variable `some_variable.stdout_lines` is an example of a string concatenation that ends up in the JSON that's posted to the URI

Here's the example playbook task

```
# here we have a parameterized JSON string ('{' + variable + '}'), 
# inside a Jinja template ({{ }}),
# inside Ansible shorthand syntax for the uri module (body=""), 
# inside a YAML string (>) for the local_action's module
- name: interact 
  local_action:
    module: >
      uri
      url=http://server:4000/api
      method=POST
      body="{{ 
               '{
                  "jsonKey0":"' + some_variable.stdout_lines[0] + '",
                  "jsonKey1": "... etc."
                }'
            }}"
      body_format=json
```